# Reason to separate query and result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there any reason why you should separate query and result when writing code, other than maybe readability?

Example separate:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY foo2 DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
```

compared to single line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY foo2 DESC LIMIT 10");
```

I usually use the 1st example but have found myself using the 2nd single line example more and more of late as its quicker and easier to write so thought I'd ask before it becomes 2nd nature and then find out its really bad and may blow up the world or something 0.o

Comment: It's a *"to each their own"*. Poh-tay-toe, poh-tah-toe.

Comment: Readability seems like quite a good one. Also, see prepared statements.

Comment: For the first one maybe it's due to the old limit of number of characters per line. But it's no longer a good reason.

Comment: When you have a where clause with bind variables; you need to prepare the statement, and then execute with the bind variables

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a preference, but readability is certainly a strong justification. However, I would also argue that scalability and maintainability of the query might also be a fitting arguments as well.  suppose you have a complex query with multiple variables being sanitized for SQL injections with joins as so forth. In other words a long query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM foo, bar Where col1.bar = (Select col1 From someTable where {$varibale} = ...) Group By ... ORDER BY foo2 DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Stuffing all of that into the function makes it difficult to read and anoying to maintain as well.

Answer (score 1):

To give an answer to this question. Do like you want (or almost).

Like I said, the first way is maybe used due to the historical where we was limited to 80 characters. But this restriction doesn't exist anymore (and we have bigger screens). By the way, I don't tell you to put 300 characters per line.

Use the one you feel more readable / maintainable with. The only drawback can be your coworkers. They can dictate which one you must use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could write your whole source in one line.

*(Minimize source = Delete all spaces and linebreaks)*

of course not in strings :)

**Effect is:**  (1 Positive and 3 Negative to do this)

- Bad readability (-)
- Faster parsing (+)
- Slow editing source (-)
- No good maintainability (-)

Not writing everything to one line

**Effect is:**  (3 Positive and 1 Negative to do this)

- Good readability (+)
- Little bit slower parsing (-)
- Fast editing source (+)
- Better maintainability  (+)

(Guess you only feel the parsingtime difference in very large codefiles)

This is how I decide to write my source.

Sometimes (for e.g. Plugins) I use the minimized version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a preference too. I usually use the short way for short and *"unvarying"* requests.

But for **longer requests**, it's easier to read and maintain taken separately.

Especially for ***"dynamic requests"*** (partly depending on external conditions): it's sometimes easier to work on a string, for example to concatenate a `where` clause, or another, or none at all, depending on a condition.
An example I have in mind: a "list.php" script displaying all articles if called with no parameter, and filtering articles of a specific category 'foo' if called with get-parameter `?cat=foo` given.
I personally find it easier to read and maintain like this:

```
$query="select name, description, price from articles";
if(isset($_GET['cat'])) $query.=" where cat={$_GET['cat']}";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
```

Of course it could also be done directly in the one-line version using ternary `(?:)` operators, but then readibility suffers a bit:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"select name, description, price from articles".(isset($_GET['cat'])?" where cat={$_GET['cat']}":""));
```

It becomes really much more unreadable and unmaintainable if you add other conditions. For instance, a second filter on get-parameter `?supplier=bar"...

[EDIT:] I just had the case: when your request fails, it's **easier to debug** when the query stands in a string. A simple `echo $query;` allows you to see exactly what you're sending to the DB server...
In following php code: `$query="select * from $userTable where id=:uid";`, you might oversee that `$userTable` wasn't defined...
but after an `echo $query;`, you can't oversee that there's something missing here: `$query="select * from where id=:uid";`...

Answer (score 0):

for me, its all about readability.  I write a ton of code. and release app.  6 months later when i go back to fix a bug, I need to quickly find things.  I separate out as much as I can.  Parsing times are minimal unless you are writing incredibly large volumes of code.  its all about readabilty for me.  I go one step further to make it as pretty as possible.

```
 $select = "SELECT x,y,z";
 $from = " FROM foo,bar,table3";
 $order = " ORDER BY foo2 DESC ";
 $limit = " LIMIT 10";
 $query = $select . $from . $order . $limit;

 $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
```